# icloud & core data enabled app freeze on first launch without internet connection on IOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, synchronization, icloud

I just create icloud integrated core data app, it's work flawlessly under normal conditions, but on first launch of application without internet connection, I've experienced strange problem on IOS 6.
Application stop responding.

I've controlled my codes and looked almost all topics related with this issue on google, but I cannot find any answer.

I've also experienced exactly the same problem on WWDC 2012 iCloud & Core Data sample code (SharedCoreData) which is published on developer portal.

on apple's sample code, I've traced this problem until, "addPersistentStoreWithType".

below you can find part of apple's code where freezing happen,
frankly, I hesitated to shared all codes because of the copyright issue of apple.

but thats, (BOOL)loadiCloudStore: called from another thread already, 
so there is no thread problem actually,
freezing just happen when "managedObjectContext" being called.

so, do you guys have any idea why "addPersistentStoreWithType" stop responding on first launch without internet connection?

```
- (BOOL)loadiCloudStore:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error {
    BOOL success = YES;
    NSError *localError = nil;

    NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    _ubiquityURL = [fm URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];

    NSURL *iCloudStoreURL = [self iCloudStoreURL];
    NSURL *iCloudDataURL = [self.ubiquityURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"iCloudData"];
    NSDictionary *options = @{ NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey : @"iCloudStore",
                                NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey : iCloudDataURL };

//after that point thread freeze
    _iCloudStore = [self.psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                          configuration:@"CloudConfig"
                                                    URL:iCloudStoreURL
                                                options:options
                                                  error:&localError];


    success = (_iCloudStore != nil);
    if (success) {
        //set up the file presenter
        _presentedItemURL = iCloudDataURL;
        [NSFileCoordinator addFilePresenter:self];
    } else {
        if (localError  && (error != NULL)) {
            *error = localError;
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

Comment: Theoretically connection to the internet should not have any effect on iCloud. Actually you communicate with your local store. The syncing part is handled by the OS.

Comment: See whether this helps

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319221/app-crash-if-icloud-is-on-linked-to-sync-with-coredata