# App Crash if iCloud is on (linked to sync with coreData)

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

This is the code i used in the init for storage class and it worked fine until recently.. when i tried testing it, it crashes (marked below) at addPersistentStoreWithType ... i noticed this after switching to the iPhone 5 and was trying to run the app... but if i turn off icloud on my phone or test it on the simulator there are no problems...

```
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
        favColors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        model = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];
        NSString *path = [self itemArchivePath];
        NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
        if (ubiq) {
            NSLog(@"iCloud access at %@", ubiq);
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(contentChange:) name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification object:nil];
            NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            NSURL *ubcontainer = [fm URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
            [options setObject:@"color" forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey];
            [options setObject:ubcontainer forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"No iCloud access");
        }
   // ************ Crash here **************
        if (![psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:(ubiq?options:nil) error:&error]) {
            [NSException raise:@"Open failed" format:@"Reason: %@", [error localizedDescription]];
        }
        context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:psc];
        [context setUndoManager:nil];

        [self loadAllItems];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *)itemArchivePath
{
    NSArray *documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"store.data"];
}
```

Also if i run the app once and turn off icloud after the crash and run the app again.. the data is retrieved from icloud... and shows on app.

The out put log shows this.

> iCloud access at file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/xxx
>   -PFUbiquitySetupAssistant performPreStoreSetupWithError:: CoreData: Ubiquity:  
>   The baseline file exists, but could not be read

Comment: Also after i went into iCloud>Storage and Backup>Manage Storage and deleted the data for the app it works fine... and the previous data is back... :/

Answer (score 2):

That's an internal iCloud error. It's not your fault, and there's nothing you can do in code that would fix or prevent it. It will happen randomly, with no predictable pattern for when or why. Deleting data for the app is, unfortunately, the only real solution. Doing that only deletes iCloud's copy of the data, not data stored in your app's Documents directory or other non-iCloud locations, so it's not surprising that the old data would still be present.

Comment: so should i put this down in the app description for people who experience this problem ?.. i don't even know if they have this problem or not.. i did and i tried it on my friend's phone, it occurred as well.

Comment: Oh, it's out in the field already? That's unfortunate. Your users will probably have problems at some point, but maybe not immediately. You probably hit it first because, since you're developing the app, you use it more. You could put it in the app description, or on your web site, but you should try to jell the, out somehow.

Comment: Cool, thnx.. was really hoping there was a fix for it.. din wanna put it in the description.

Comment: Isn't there something like a try catch I can put that in to counter the error ?

Comment: If the app is crashing, using try/catch would help you avoid the crash, but it would not help you get iCloud working. The app could keep running but would not be able to access its data or sync that data.

Comment: So maybe I can send a alertview to delete data on iCloud if there's an error and it'll resync ?

Comment: Maybe. With iCloud it's hard to be sure.